# SparkSQL - some partitions appear in HiveServer2 but not SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, apache-spark-sql

Hive external table is pointing to files on S3, ddl includes partitioned by eod clause. Under a folder there are 5 subfolders, each with a file underneath for different partition_date. ie

```
eod=20180602/fileA
eod=20180603/fileA
eod=20180604/fileA
eod=20180605/fileA
eod=20180606/fileA
```

Msck repair table is run on HiveServer2

select distinct part_dt from tbl on HiveServer2 (port 10000) returns all 5 dates

However, select distinct part_dt from tbl on SparkThriftServer (ie SparkSQL, port 10015) returns only the first 2 dates.

How is this possible?

Even when running msck repair on SparkThriftServer the discrepancy still exists.

The file schema is same on all dates. (ie each file has same number/type of columns)

Comment: I assume the metastore is correctly setup by Spark?

Comment: got any link to point me to about correct setup?

Comment: I do not. There is a Hive site XML file that should roughly match between your Spark installation and the Hive client

Comment: the 2 hive-sites are same. Interesting thing is that we have ~2000 tables, 1992 of them are fine. Just 8 affected and within those 8 some partitions are showing while some are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, those 8 affected tables were previously cached in sparksql (ie `cache table <table>`). Once i ran `uncache table <table>` all partitions lined up again!